# PrimeFaces "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly" error with DataTable

Tags: javascript, jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have been trying to use the DataTable component from PrimeFaces but it keeps throwing the following error in IE 7.0.5 and latest version of FireFox:

```
A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly
```

The only time that do not get this error is if I remove all my DataTables (total of 3) and with the exception of the main one, which only displays a max of 5 rows.  The other two DataTables only have about 250 rows.  I got rid of pagination, sorting, filtering and still get the error message.  Those tables used to be displayed inside a TabView (one tab for each DataTable).  I also got rid of this and displayed the DataTables directly on the page inside a ScrollPanel.  Still no luck...

Please help!  I have worked on this thinkg all night and yesterday...

I am using PF 3.0 (also tried 3.0.1).

I am actually thinking about dropping it altogether as it is wasting my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup with `TabView` with 2 tabs and 2 `DataTables`. Since my tables are potentially much bigger than yours, I have chosen to implement `LazyLoading` on both tables.

And it works fine on both browsers.

I'd say that 250 rows are enough for considering to implement `LazyLoading` in your case, too.

Comment: Thanks.  I will spend some time implementing LazyLoading to see if it helps.  My DataTables also have the potential to be much large eg 10,000 rows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  It looks like it is solving my problem with a quick test.  I now need to implement it in the actual application.

Comment: I updated the code in my actual application and all works great... Thanks again.